# What is the setting for changing language in Safari through Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, safari, localization, webdriver

I'm trying to change the default language in Safari through WebDriver. I know this is the way in Chrome:

```
        val chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        val prefs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "fr-CA");
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

How can this be accomplished for Safari?

Comment: I am looking for the answer to, did you find the solution ?

Comment: Same for me on Safari (16.4.1) with Selenium (selenium-java:4.9.0). The lack of any information anywhere on this is really odd.

Comment: I've reposted the original question on https://developer.apple.com/forums/ and will update here if accepted and again if answered.

Comment: Posted to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730736